# How to access two different methods of the same object concurrently in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a use case where I want to separate a complex computation into two parts (in two different methods) and calculate them concurrently. In other words, I will have a class like this:

```
class A 

public synchronized double computeOne {****};

public synchronized double computeTwo {****};
```

Is it possible for me to start two threads, and have threadA run computeOne, threadB run computeTwo (one the same instance of classA)?

I feel like this won't work because only one method can grab the monitor in the specific instance of class A. 
Then... How can I accomplish my goal with the concurrent feature?

Comment: Did you try with threads? What were the results? Any exceptions?

Comment: If you want them to be callable concurrently, why are they synchronized?

Comment: "I feel like this won't work because only one method can grab the monitor in the specific instance of class A. "
So don't *feel like* - just try it out and *then* ask!

Comment: It appears to me that one of the method calls will be blocked until the other one finishes the computation so I am not gaining anything from using two threads.

Comment: Jon - very good and direct comment! I think I am a bit confused on the concurreny part (newbie on this). I thought only by declaring a method to be synchronized can it be used in multiple threads..

Comment: So.. If I remove the synchronized keyword, just declare them to be normal methods. Then put them into two different runnable objects and two different threads, it should work fine? I am going to give this a try later tonight.

Comment: Declaring a method synchronized prevents that method or any other synching on the same object from being simultaneously entered in more than one thread.  If there is no reason to "fear" concurrent operation then there is no need to synchronize.  (Using the `synchronized` statement vs a synchronized method allows you to sync on some other object.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use the lock on your object, you can specify separate locks:

```
class A {
    private final Object lock1 = new Object();
    private final Object lock2 = new Object();

    public double computeOne {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            ****
        }
    }

    public double computeTwo {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            ****
        }
    } 
}
```

This assumes these two methods won't interfere with each other by tampering with state that the other uses. That you're wanting to call these things concurrently suggests the object could stand to be reworked and split into separate objects with more focused responsibility.

Synchronizing on internal locks is a recommended practice anyway, so that not just anything can come along and acquire a lock.

It would be preferable if you could remove any state from the calculation so that you could avoid locking altogether. If the only state is local to the method then you don't have to lock.

Comment: Cool. I think this is what I am looking for. Since I am sure computeOne and computeTwo can be handled concurrently without affecting each other, I can create two objects within the class A instance just to provide finer control to lock different parts of the instance. I am glad java provides this type of flexibility in an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan's code with using java.util.concurrent

```
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public static class A {
    private final Lock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Lock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();

    public void computeOne() {
        try {
            lock1.lock();
            // your code
        } finally {
            lock1.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void computeTwo() {
        try {
            lock2.lock();
            // your code
        } finally {
            lock2.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```